# Duplicate part of gitlab repository to another repository inside gitlab

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-pipelines

I have a Shared Server running IIS that accepts Git automatic deployment, I am using .Net 2.2.
Files will be deployed to the plesk  website as soon as they are pushed to the gitlab repository using SSH and WebHooks.
So this repository will only have deployed, e.g: dll files.
I have another repository for the repository in gitlab.

I am able to publish locally by the command bellow in pipeline.

```
 publish-to-dev:
  stage: publish-to-dev
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish -c Release'
```

**Question:** How can I create a pipeline command that will copy the deployed files from the **code repository** to the **deployment repository**  after the deployment command `dotnet publish`?

**EDIT**

Question was answered by Mike bellow, but I am getting an error on the process of copying file, I am getting the message like bellow:

```
$ cp artifacts/emaua/* deploy/
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/cs'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/de'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/es'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/fr'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/it'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/ja'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/ko'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/pl'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/pt-BR'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/refs'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/ru'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/runtimes'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/tr'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/wwwroot'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/zh-Hans'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'artifacts/emaua/zh-Hant'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**Solved** by adding `-r` like `- 'cp -r path/to/published/files/* deploy/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use GitLab Artifacts

The [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) command will build the project and then put the output files to a folder on the build system.

This will be a folder on the GitLab Runner machine that's running the `publish-to-dev` job.

If you want to be able to download the `publish`ed files from GitLab, then you can use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to specify that the directory containing the published files be zipped up and attached to the job after it completes.

```yaml
 publish-to-dev:
  stage: publish-to-dev
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish -c Release'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - path/to/published/files/
```

The files will be available as `artifacts.zip` on the job (on the right-hand side bar).

#### Caveats:

This doesn't *actually* put the published files into the **deployment repository**. To do that you would have to download the ZIP and then add it to the repo yourself.

---

### Use `git` inside your job

Alternatively, since you want to push these to the other repository, then things get more tricky. You need to do these things:

- Get an [access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#project-access-tokens) for the **deployment repository**
- Store this in a [pipeline variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#gitlab-cicd-variables) for the **code repository** - in my example below, it's called `DEPLOY_REPO_TOKEN`
- Retrieve the token in your job (using `variables`), and use it to authenticate when you do `git` operations to the **deployment repository**
- In the `publish-to-dev` job, `git clone` the **deployment repository** (using the token), `git add` the published files, and then `git push`, something like this:

```yaml
 variables:
  DEPLOY_REPO_TOKEN: $DEPLOY_REPO_TOKEN
  DEPLOY_REPO_URL: 'gitlab.example.com/group/project/deployment-repository'
 publish-to-dev:
  stage: publish-to-dev
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish -c Release'
    - `git clone https://oauth2:$DEPLOY_REPO_TOKEN@$DEPLOY_REPO_URL.git deploy'
    - 'cp -r path/to/published/files/* deploy/'
    - 'cd deploy'
    - 'git add .'
    - 'git commit -m "deployed"'
    - 'git push'
```

#### Caveats:

- I haven't looked ino the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal` image to see if this is dotnet on a Linux (so that the `cp` command will work), or if it's a Windows image (requiring `copy` instead, and different path separators).
- Also the image would require the `git` command to be present, or else you'll have to install that first.

Comment: thanks a lot for the awesome answer, there was just one part that is failing in my case. 
The     - 'cp artifactory/files/* deploy/' is failing at some point, it works in the beginning and after it ommits some files and it fails, I will update it on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion 

Comment: Mike, I should be thankful for your help. :) Could you upvote or if know the solution help me with the other gitlab problem I am encountering right now? This time is with angular pipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768740/ng-build-fails-cannot-find-module

Comment: I've generalized this as a snippet for other projects: https://gitlab.com/milohax/hax/-/snippets/2226609